# SQLAlchemy: How to auto increment based on multiple keys?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy and Mysql. I have a table for invoices. It's shared for different companies. Like this:

```
class Invoice(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'invoice'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    company = Column(Integer)
    invoiceNumber = Column(Integer)
```

When I create a new Invoice the invoiceNumber should be incremented with one compared to the last invoiceNumber for that company. The invoiceNumber must be ever increasing and unique per company.

How can I achieve that with SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 0):

You can use that:

```
from sqlalchemy.event import listen
from sqlalchemy.sql.functions import func
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, UniqueConstraint

class Invoice(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'invoice'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    company = Column(Integer)
    invoiceNumber = Column(Integer)

    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint(company, invoiceNumber),)

    @staticmethod
    def increment(mapper, connection, invoice):
        last = Session.query(func.max(Invoce.invoiceNumber).label('last')\
            .filter(Invoice.company == invoice.company).first()
        invoice.last = last.last if last else 1

listen(Invoice, "before_insert", Invoice.increment)
```

Something like that. [There are](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/event.html) more information about sqlalchemy events listeners.
Or, you can implement [database trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html), which will be have the same logic